# Java - Sum of prime numbers of random-generated array-values

Tags: java, oop, random, primes

I am a beginner in Java and I have a task to do, to calculate the sum of prime numbers from the random-generated values of an array.

So, I was told that I should have 3 classes:

1) MyArray - where I have already written this code:

```
...
public int[] createArray(int n) {
    int[] a = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = rnd.nextInt(10);
    }
    return a;
}
...
```

2) IsPrime - where I should do the checking if a number is a prime or not. The problem is I don't know how to 'connect' the array from MyArray to the IsPrime class. I started with a boolean method checkPrime, that has an object m from the MyArray class as a parameter, but I don't know how to continue, how to access the array from the IsPrime class.

I am thankful for any given opinions and advice. Thank you!

P.S. 
My third class Run.java has the main-method.

Comment: Can you share your code, or at least the method signatures? It will make the question much clearer and will help us help you

Comment: 3 classes or 3 methods?

Comment: @Mureinik I don't have much code. In MyArray.java I have just the code I've written previously and after that just another method public void print(int[] a), where I just print the values of the array. In the second class - IsPrime.java I have just this: public boolean checkPrime(MyArray m), and I don't know how to continue...

Comment: @suvojit_007 3 different classes: MyArray.java where I fill the array with random values, IsPrime.java where I should check if a number is prime or not and Run.java where I have the main-method and print the sum of primes.

Comment: How can an `array` be prime?

Comment: @TheHeadRush Not the array. The values (numbers) of the array that are random-generated.

Comment: We agree that an array cannot be prime. What i don't understand is why are passing an array to the method that evaluates whether a number is prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should basically look like that:

```
MyArray myArray = new MyArray();
IsPrime isPrime = new IsPrime();

int sum = 0;
for(int num : myArray.createArray(20)){
    if(isPrime.checkPrime(num)){
        sum += num;
    }
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Put it into your main method in Run class

Answer (score 0):

You can call IsPrime method from Run Class like below

```
Class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args]) {

        IsPrime ip=new IsPrime();

        int sum= ip.checkPrime();

        System.out.print(sum);

    }
}


Class IsPrime {    
    public int checkPrime(int length){ MyArray m=
    MyArray ();  int[] arr = m.createArray(5);

    //iterating arr and call to isPrime() method

    }

    public boolean isPrime(int num){ 

        // prime checking logic  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I am writing from mobile. Pls ignore formatting issues

Answer (score 0):

You should declare in the class where you have the array.
In the class isPrime, you should declare a method that sums all the prime number, received in the parameter int[].
Just as an idea, and to be quicker, you can use ForkJoinPool to create multiple Threads, but I think that is not your main target for the moment.

```
    public class YourClass{

        private int[] MyArray;

    //Constructor
    //Methods

    //Getter of MyArray
        public int[] getMyArray(){
            return this.MyArray;
        }
    };
```